# How to pause the news slider on mouse hover and play on mouse out.?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<body>
<ul id="ticker">
    <li>
        <p>Innovation - The Power of 4S The progress of Auto Industry stands on the four basic pillars.</p>
        <p>The S pillars and it would not be an overstatement that the combination thr illed the Auto-Indutry.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>Innovation - The Power of 4S The progress of Auto Industry stands on the four basic pillars.</p>
        <p>The S pillars and it would not be an overstatement that the combination thr illed the Auto-Indutry.</p>

    </li>
    <li>
        <p>Innovation - The Power of 4S The progress of Auto Industry stands on the four basic pillars.</p>
        <p>The S pillars and it would not be an overstatement that the combination thr illed the Auto-Indutry.</p>
    </li>
</ul>


<script>
function tick(){
    $('#ticker li:first').slideUp( function () { $(this).appendTo($('#ticker')).slideDown(); });
}
setInterval(function(){ tick () }, 2000);
```

this is the code for simple news slider. 
How to pause the news slider on mouse hover and play on mouse out.?

Answer (score 0):

Assign your setInterval to a variable, so there's just the one interval object you can reuse.

var interval_id = setInterval(...

On your hover events, use clearInterval(interval_id) to stop it, and reinstate it on mouse leave/out.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

The basic idea is to clear the `setInterval` on hover which should stop slider and then reinitiate it on mouseout.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     var clearTick = setInterval(function(){ tick () }, 2000);         

     $('div').hover(
         function () {
           clearInterval(clearTick);

         }, 
         function () {
           clearTick = setInterval(function(){ tick () }, 2000);

         }
     );

   });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sliderTick = setInterval(function(){ tick () }, 2000);

$('#ticker li').mouseover(function(){
     clearInterval(sliderTick);
}

$('#ticker li').mouseout(function(){
     sliderTick = setInterval(function(){ tick () }, 2000);
}
```

Basically stop calling the function when the mouse is over and resume on mouse out

Answer (score 0):

Not jQuery tagged, but you are using jQuery.

You can use [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) to know when you are hovering your element, and [`setInteval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval) and [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.clearInterval) to start/stop your slider.

Code:

```
function tick(){
    $('#ticker li:first').slideUp( function () { $(this).appendTo($('#ticker')).slideDown(); });
}

var ticker=setInterval(function(){ tick () }, 2000);

$('#ticker').hover(
  function() {
    clearInterval(ticker);
  }, function() {
    ticker=setInterval(function(){ tick () }, 2000);
  }
);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/gcVN5/